# Similarities of a function and its fourier transformation

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Given is the function 
$f(t)=\begin{cases}4&\text{$-1 \leq t \leq 1$,}\\0&\text{$-2 \leq t < -1 ∧ 1  < t \leq 2$.}\end{cases}$

I've calculated its fourier transformation and got $$g(t) =2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(8\cdot \sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}))}{n\pi}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}t)$$

Now I must tell in which points the function $f(t)$ is equal to its fourier transformation $g(t)$ and in which they differ. I've plotted the [fourier transformation with wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2BSum%5B8*sin(n*pi%2F2)%2F(n*pi)+*+cos((n*pi*t)%2F2)+,+%7Bn,+1,+4%7D%5D) but I'am not sure about the answer. 
I guess that they are equal, when $t = 0$ and maybe when $t=-2$ and $t=2$, otherwise they differ. Does this make any sense?

Comment: The value of the Fourier series of $f$ equals $f$ where $f$ is continuous, but not where $f$ has a step.

Comment: Do you mean, that they are equal for this values:  −2 < t < −1 ∧ −1 < t < 1 ∧ 1 < t < 2

Comment: I noticed now that the sum in the expression for $g(t)$ only goes to $N$, not to $\infty$. If $g$ should be the Fourier series, i.e. if the sum has upper limit $\infty$, then $f = g$ on those open intervals, but also at $t=2$ since the periodized function is continuous there. If the upper limit really should be $N$ then it's more difficult to tell where $f(t) = g(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess that it should be $\infty$, so I've corrected it. I wasn't sure which formula to use, as we had one with $N$ and another one with $\infty$.